# request.getParameterValues getting null in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am making an ajax call to a jsp page like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'update.jsp',
    data: {testarray:[["j1_1", "", "Tab 1", ""],["j1_2", "j1_1", "Item 1", ""],["j1_3", "", "Tab 2", ""]]},
    success: callback,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;",
});
```

And in update.jsp, I am trying to get the value of *testarray* parameter with this:

```
String[] testArrayValue=request.getParameterValues('testarray');
System.out.println(testArrayValue);
```

And the console print says *testArray*  value is **null**.
Can anyone pint me into the right direction?
Thanks in advance, 
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different approaches, but in the end I came with a not-so-elegant-but-functional solution: i converted *testarray* to string , and then in the jsp page I split it and did the magic. Anyways, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
request.getParameterValues('testarray');
```

TO:

```
request.getParameterValues("testarray");
```

Comment: Why would it even compile when the single-quotes are used??

Answer (score 0):

You can use also **split()**  method of String class like that:

```
    String[] parameters[] = request.getParameter("testarray").split(",");
```